# YouTube Api Video Upload Code Not working

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i have found a code for uploading video on youtube in my own channel but its show some error.. can help to find i try every thing to sort out this problem...

```
      <?php

       $youtube_email = "email"; // Change this to your youtube sign in         email.
      $youtube_password = "password"; // 
                    $postdata = "Email=".$youtube_email."&Passwd=".$youtube_password."&service=youtube&source=Example";
            $curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            print_r($response);
            curl_close($curl);

            list($auth, $youtubeuser) = explode("\n", $response);
            list($authlabel, $authvalue) = array_map("trim", explode("=", $auth));
            list($youtubeuserlabel, $youtubeuservalue) = array_map("trim", explode("=", $youtubeuser));

            $youtube_video_title = "Example"; // This is the uploading video title.
            $youtube_video_description = "Example"; // This is the uploading video description.
            $youtube_video_category = "News"; // This is the uploading video category.
            $youtube_video_keywords = "example, video"; // This is the uploading video keywords.

            $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                        <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                          xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                          xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
                          <media:group>
                            <media:title type="plain">'.$youtube_video_title.'</media:title>
                            <media:description type="plain">'.$youtube_video_description.'</media:description>
                            <media:category
                              scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">'.$youtube_video_category.'</media:category>
                            <media:keywords>'.$youtube_video_keywords.'</media:keywords>
                          </media:group>
                        </entry>';

            $key = "apikey"; // Get your key here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/.

            $headers = array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$authvalue,
                             "GData-Version: 2",
                             "X-GData-Key: key=".$key,
                             "Content-length: ".strlen($data),
                             "Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");

            $curl = curl_init("http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

            $response = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($curl));
            print_r($response);
            curl_close($curl);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function checkForFile() {
                if (document.getElementById('file').value) {
                  return true;
                }
                document.getElementById('errMsg').style.display = '';
                return false;
              }
            </script>

            <?php
            $nexturl = "http://localhost/youtube.php"; // This parameter specifies the URL to which YouTube will redirect the user's browser when the user uploads his video file.
            ?>

            <form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">
              <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
              <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
                You need to specify a file.
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
              <input type="submit" value="go" />

            </form>
```

but its show some error

```
        Error=BadAuthentication Url=https://www.google.com/accounts/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuh0dduQUt6wddYfCPGzt13_2yHJDHeRIjGmBk9J6Fpou-BfaoCRULdEWuHxbUZmrBzvQhw0obSD9bQwUEUazXQT33PdBPtWLO0RxIe9gST-vdrwi7sValAtw1AX3x5TE_56TosAb32oOhY4kXHNDAIRE_gd8IZAwigT2mAjr47IaISoBWmNZyYSepTNApJVeLwN7_HQqUwSnU0avOUqfO3DZKwgZAfXKKdQn5jYym6B_-dLHc Info=WebLoginRequired 

      SimpleXMLElement Object ( [error] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [domain] => yt:authentication [code] => Unknown ) )
```

i have try some other but they work some time or some time not and upload the video on user channel...

I am waiting for suggestion..

Comment: do you have an API key and an oAuth token to authenticate the request? Can't see that in the code `$key = "apikey"; // Get your key here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/.` AFAIK userid/password login for Google Services is deprecated / removed and you need to take oAuth2 flow

Comment: yes i have api key/// and i have done it with oauth but when i use outh its upload video on user channel not mine

Comment: Then you need to get yourself an access_token which is pointing to your own channel and not to someone else's channel / account ??? I recommend to re-read all the stuff about Authentication and then grab the examples from Google instead of trying to get outdated code to work

Comment: how to get access token on my own channel and replace it with getAccessToken method...?

Comment: Once you follow the oAuth2 flow and login with **YOUR** uid/pwd, the access token is **YOUR** channel access token. RTFM!

Comment: yes i got the access token from oAuth2playground... but where i will place it for authenticating

Comment: i have seen the code for access token